# Limit on Pandas groupby count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have DataFrame `crimes_df`:

```
>> crimes_df.size
6198374
```

I need to calculate events with the same `"s_lat"`, `"s_lon"` and `"date"`. I use groupby:

```
crimes_count_df = crimes_df\
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"])\
    .size()\
    .to_frame("crimes")
```

But it doesn't give the correct answer because if you calculate sum you can see that most events were lost:

```
>> crimes_count_df.sum()
crimes    476798
dtype: int64
```

I've also tried agg:

```
crimes_count_df = crimes_df\
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"])\
    .agg(['count'])
```

But the same result:

```
crimes_count_df.sum()
Unnamed: 0            count    476798
area                  count    476798
arrest                count    476798
description           count    476798
domestic              count    476798
latitude              count    476798
location_description  count    475712
longitude             count    476798
time                  count    476798
type                  count    476798
```

EDIT: 
I found out there is a limit on this aggregation functions! See this commands:

```
crimes_df.head(100) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    100
dtype: int64

crimes_df.head(1000) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    1000
dtype: int64

crimes_df.head(10000) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    10000
dtype: int64

crimes_df.head(100000) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    100000
dtype: int64

crimes_df.head(1000000) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    476798
dtype: int64

crimes_df.head(10000000) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    476798
dtype: int64

crimes_df.head(476799) \
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"]) \
    .size() \
    .to_frame("crimes")\
    .sum()
crimes    476798
dtype: int64
```

If you want to check it yourself, here is file with data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib0kq16t4c2e5a2/CrimeDataWithSquare.csv?dl=0

You can load it this way:

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
crimes_df = read_csv("CrimeDataWithSquare.csv")
```

Info

```
crimes_df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 476798 entries, 0 to 476797
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Unnamed: 0              476798 non-null int64
area                    476798 non-null float64
arrest                  476798 non-null bool
date                    476798 non-null object
description             476798 non-null object
domestic                476798 non-null bool
latitude                476798 non-null float64
location_description    475712 non-null object
longitude               476798 non-null float64
time                    476798 non-null object
type                    476798 non-null object
s_lon                   476798 non-null float64
s_lat                   476798 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(2), float64(5), int64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 40.9+ MB
```

Comment: Contain NaN ? in your data

Comment: show crime_df.info()

Comment: I don't get it:
crimes_df.size
6198374
len(crimes_df.reset_index())
476798
len(crimes_df)
476798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not a bug. The size method is not always equals to number of rows. Let's look your case:

```
import pandas as pd

crimes_df = pd.read_csv("CrimeDataWithSquare.csv")

crimes_df.shape

#(476798, 13)

crimes_df.shape[0] * crimes_df.shape[1]

#6198374

crimes_df.size

#6198374

len(crimes_df)

#476798
```

What documentation says about the `size` method?

[number of elements in the NDFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html)

Generally, Dataframe has 2 dimensions (X rows by Y columns). Thus, the dataframe `size` method returns X times Y (number of elements in it).

What if you have one single column?

```
crimes_df2 = crimes_df.iloc[:, 0]
len(crimes_df2) == crimes_df2.size

#True
```

It's the result you were expecting for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3] * 4,
    'b': np.random.choice(['q','w','a'], size=12),
    'c': 1
})

df
    a  b  c
0   1  q  1
1   2  w  1
2   3  q  1
3   1  w  1
4   2  w  1
5   3  a  1
6   1  q  1
7   2  a  1
8   3  q  1
9   1  q  1
10  2  q  1
11  3  a  1

df.groupby(['a', 'b']).count()

     c
a b   
1 q  3
  w  1
2 a  1
  q  1
  w  2
3 a  2
  q  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that some of your dataset could have missing values, such as date?
If I recall correctly, a None is not going to group (though I could be wrong).
Have you tried using fillna(0)?

```
crimes_count_df = crimes_df\
    .groupby(["s_lat", "s_lon", "date"])\
    .size()\
    .reset_index()\
    .fillna(0)\
    .to_frame("crimes")
```

Comment: Result is still 476798